# My chrome browser hint breakpoint in the wrong line when I debug JavaScript code in pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use google chrome for many years. Recently I use chrome to debug JavaScript code in my project, I just set the breakpoint using chrome dev-tool that these breakpoints seems to be ignored, but the js function certainly be executed. My JS code and the breakpoint position like this picture:
[js breakpoint can't be hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8dz6.png)

When I the breakpoint is hinted, the hint line is the wrong line and the variables are present the message "xxx is not defined":
[hint breakpoint in the wrong line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYkPB.png)

My OS is Windows 10, chrome edition is 72.0.3626.119.

Answer (score 0):

One Possible reason for that is by mistake you might have the Deactivate Breakpoint enabled. Because of that the chrome debugger not stopping on any breakpoints. Attaching 2 image for references, where the first one is enabled for breakpoints [Image with enabled breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tvBk.png) and the second one [Image with disabled breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjO5U.png) is disabled.

Comment: I'm quite sure i enable the breakpoint. I'm sorry for the wrong question description. In my case, I can hint the breakpoint, but the breakpoint present in the wrong line and all the variables have the same message "xx is not defined"